# In Argentina, am I expected to tip the delivery guy if the restaurant already charged me a delivery fee?

Tags: local-customs, argentina, tipping

I know tipping is voluntary in Argentina, but tipping the delivery guy is customary here and I do when there's no delivery fee. The restaurant in question is already charging me a rather high amount for the delivery (20 ARS), which makes me wonder if I should tip or not.

Comment: Tipping is by definition voluntary...

Comment: Delivery fee is not a tips in any country